# How to validate MVC3 custom object properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have following code, but validation for the custom type(`UserDetails`) are not firing. Is there any way to overcome this problem? I know that if i define all the properties of `UserDetails` inside `UserModel`, it will work fine. but i need to reuse the `UserDetails`

Model,

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public UserDetails User { get; set; }
}
```

Custom object,

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [Required]
    public string FirtstName { get; set; }  

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} can not be greater than {1} characters")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

View,

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.UserDetails.Address , new { rows = "5", cols = "20"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserDetails.Address )
....
```

Comment: Just remembered something else:
Try putting [Required] attibute on the User property in UserModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just because of the ID and name of the element. for example in this case name of the FirtstName control is `UserModel.FirtstName` and ID is `UserModel_FirtstName` so client side validation will not fire in this case. if you want to add validation you have to add client validation manually. but you can validate it in the server side by using `ModelState.IsValid`

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if( ModelState.IsValidField("UserDetails.FirstName"))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserDetails.FirstName", "Error in save");
    }
    ......
}
```

client side validation

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "UserDetails.FirstName": { required: true }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about client side validation - make sure that your view code is placed within

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    ...
}
```

block and you have client side validation enabled with something like   `@{Html.EnableClientValidation(); }`

I.e.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Password change was unsuccessful")

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
            ..............
```

As for triggering server-side validation - you should call Model.IsValid in your action

**EDIT:**

Just remembered something else:
Try putting [Required] attibute on the User property in UserModel

Comment: i already have `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and it is not validating. this is not only for client side validation.

Comment: I had messed up sentence order in my post - changed it a bit.
As for validation - it your code seems valid - I cannot remember anything else. Maybe you have configuration issue etc.. If you provide full example I can look into it

Answer (score 0):

why not create your own validation rules. you can use Ivalidatable Object. check for this link, it has nice explanationation

1. [Asp.net Ivalidatable object implementation](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/31/ASPNETMVC3ValidationIValidatableObject.aspx)
2. [Validation in asp.net mvc3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/07/28/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-validatepasswordlengthattribute-in-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)